# How to check if the user is already logged in or not using Cookie?

Tags: asp.net, security

I want to know how can I detect if the user is already logged in or not? using a cookie. I am not using any log-in control. I have a db which checks the ID and PWD.
Also pls let me know if it can be done without using cookies.
Any code or links will help.
web.config:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="myForm" loginUrl="LogIn.aspx" path="/" defaultUrl="Home.aspx">
</forms>
  </authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
   </authorization>
```

Thanks

Comment: Would be nice to accept the answer since I took the time to answer your question, or at least edit your question to be more specific

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In asp.net using windows / forms authentication you can tell if the user is logged in via :

```
<%
   Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
%>
```

Forms Authentication is cookie based, but can be configured to not use cookies with the cookieless setting.

How to fully setup forms authentication is not a quick answer but it is relatively easy to setup there are many HOW-TO's online. Here is a good one https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150650/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110701-1.shtml

MSDN :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx

You can use Windows Authentication also which does not use cookies.

Comment: @Somu What exactly do you want? The links I provided will show you exactly how to setup forms authentication. Do you want me to reproduce/duplicate that code? Please be specific is there is something that you do not understand in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

I used:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated
```

Comment: This is to validate the request is authenticated, not the user.