# Why is web user authenticated through NTLM?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using forms authentication and launching a site from Visual Studio 2010.  It is using the Visual Studio Development (web) Server and not IIS.  The web.config has:

```
<authenticaion mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".MyApp" protection="All" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
</authentication>
```

The login page is using the ASP.NET login control.  Before the user even logs in, I can see following:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.AuthenticationType == "NTLM"
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity == System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.AuthenticationType == "NTLM"
```

This user seems to be authenticated as a local system user and not a web user.  Doesn't this mean the user will always be authenticated, regardless if they logged into the site or not?

How is a web user NTLM?

Comment: What's your authentication setup in IIS look like?

Comment: `Request.LogonUserIdentity` represents how IIS is being run.

Comment: @Erix: As mentioned above, I'm not using IIS.

Comment: @Daniel, is there a way to verify the web user's authentication through forms authentication?  Or does it not deal with that?

Comment: This looks to be the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833786/how-to-check-if-the-user-is-already-logged-in-or-not-using-cookie.  Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

Comment: @4thSpace VS2010 server runs on IIS but a sort of compact version of it

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses: Ok.  In regards to the OP, Page.User is correct over HttpContext.Current.User.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know cassini does does not support Windows authentication.

Its runs as a local system account and thats what you see as NTLM authenticated.

If you are developping/debugging security features for an Asp.Net application (or WCF) I highly suggest you deploy to IIS.

Comment: You guys (and @EdSF) both posted similar good answers.  Not sure who to accept.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you're seeing `yourself` as being the `User` (being authenticated) running Visual Studio (in your user context) when you are debugging using VS and it's dev server.

Visual Studio runs in your context (your Windows user account/permissions, etc.) - `Request.LogonUserIdentity.User`

It shouldn't affect your debugging of Web Forms/Forms Authentication. After successful Forms Auth Login, you can obtain `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` of the "forms auth user" (web user).